# Basic Python Loops

Tags: python, loops

```
import time

age = input("How old? ")
guess = 0
count = 0

while guess != age:
        guess = input("What's your guess? ")
        if guess == age:
                print("Correct!")
        else:
                print("Wrong!")
        count = count + 1
        print("You guessed wrong this many times:{1} ".format(count))

while count <= 0:
        print("You messed up this many times: {0} ".format(count))
        count = count - 1
        time.sleep(5)
```

I'm new to python/coding, so forgive any mistakes or misunderstanding.  I need to get rid of the line that says "you guessed wrong this many times:[4]" after I correctly guess the number, as shown here:

[image: Current behavior]

Instead, I need it to roll out the information like this:

[image: Desired Behavior]

Comment: Images are not attached, can you please attach the images

Comment: I edited the question, but not sure if I got the image order correct. Can you confirm @yames?

Comment: To be clear, you want the "You messed up..." message to show up once for each time the user got it wrong, or just once at the end?

Comment: Make `count = 0` if you get it right

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. Please look up the `break` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You should place it on right place, in `else` block

```
while guess != age:
    guess = input("What's your guess? ")
    if guess == age:
            print("Correct!")
            break
    else:
            print("Wrong!")
            print("You guessed wrong this many times:{1} ".format(count+1))
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: What happens after the age is guessed correctly? What's the point of staying in the loop?

Comment: you are right, there is no need to execute count=count+1 when guessed correctly

Answer (score 0):

A `break` statement would end the loop as soon as the user guesses correctly:

```
while guess != age:
        guess = input("What's your guess? ")
        if guess == age:
                print("Correct!")
                break #Ends 'nearest' loop
        else:
                print("Wrong!")
        count = count + 1
        print("You guessed wrong this many times:{1} ".format(count)) #Never gets here if correct
```

Read about `break` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm

Also, I'm assuming you want `while count >= 0:` as `while count <= 0:` will never run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` to exit the loop upon success

```
count = 1
while guess != age:
    guess = input("What's your guess? ")
    if guess == age:
        print("Correct!")
        break
    print("Wrong!")
    print(f"You guessed wrong this many times: {count}")
    count += 1
```